# How to implement class which can be used to de-serialize multiple level json?

Tags: c#, oop, jsonconvert

I have a json string like:

```json
{
    "sn_request": {
        "sn_body": {
            "getExtensionlink": {
                "pid": null,
                "productUrl": "https://xx",
                "promotionId": null,
                "quanUrl": null,
                "subUser": null,
                "sugsUrl": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Due to that node `getExtensionlink` is dynamic, I implement the class like below:

```cs
public class SnRequest<T>
{
    public T sn_body { get; set; }
}

public class Root<T>
{
    public SnRequest<T> sn_request { get; set; }
}

public class GetExtensionlink<T>
{
    public T getExtensionlink { get; set; }
}

public class GetExtensionlinkTest
{
    [JsonProperty("pid")]
    public string Pid { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("productUrl")]

    public string ProductUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("promotionId")]

    public string PromotionId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("quanUrl")]

    public string QuanUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("subUser")]

    public string SubUser { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("sugsUrl")]

    public string SugsUrl { get; set; }
}
```

And then, deserialize it by code below:

```cs
var getExtensionlinkT = new GetExtensionlinkTest
{
    ProductUrl = @"https://m.suning.com/product/0071237944/000000012059477830.html?utm_campaign=1608091212288684183&utm_source=share-copyurl&utm_medium=2cd5ed46-copyurl"
};

var root = new Root<GetExtensionlink<GetExtensionlinkTest>>
{
    sn_request = new SnRequest<GetExtensionlink<GetExtensionlinkTest>>
    {
        sn_body = new GetExtensionlink<GetExtensionlinkTest>
        {
            getExtensionlink = getExtensionlinkT
        }                    
    }
};

var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<Root<GetExtensionlink<GetExtensionlinkTest>>, TestResponseBase<GetExtensionlink<GetExtensionlinkResponse>>>(@"https://xx", root);
```

But, this line `Root<GetExtensionlink<GetExtensionlinkTest>` make a little unacceptable.

I hope whether there is any way will make above code clean and reuseable.

Comment: Why do you use generics?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what does it mean *getExtensionlink is dynamic*? Do you want to serialize only those fields that contains value (and omit rest of them)?

Comment: For `getExtensionlink is dynamic`, it means, `sn_body` may change to other content like `"getxxlink": {
                "xxproperty": "xx"               
            }`, and that's why I used generics. @PeterCsala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making use of the `JObject`?

#### Simplified example

```
class Root
{
    public JObject Body { get; set; }
}

class X
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Y
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

So I have a top entity and 2 different sub-entities.

#### Serialization

```
var a = new Root { Body = JObject.FromObject(new X {Id = 1}) };
var b = new Root { Body = JObject.FromObject(new Y {Desc = "Test"}) };

var jsonA = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
var jsonB = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b);

Console.WriteLine(jsonA);
Console.WriteLine(jsonB);
```

Here we are using the `FromObject` to convert sub-entities into `JObject`s.

The output

```json
{"Body":{"Id":1}}
{"Body":{"Desc":"Test"}}
```

#### Deserialization

```cs
var rootA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonA);
var rootB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonB);

var x = rootA.Body.ToObject<X>();
var y = rootB.Body.ToObject<Y>();

Console.WriteLine(x.Id);
Console.WriteLine(y.Desc);
```

Here we are using the `ToObject` to convert `JObject`s sub-entities into.

---

With this approach you don't need to pass all the way down the generic parameter.